# How to update a sideloaded APPX on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10, windows-mobile, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, appx

**Problem:**

I have created two APPX-files with version 0.0.1 and version 0.0.2. After the installation of version 0.0.1 the app is visible and accessible. All is ok so far.

Now I want to update that app to version 0.0.2. I open the 0.0.2 APPX-file and the installation pop-up comes up. I press the install button and the app seems to install, same like the 0.0.1 installation. After about a minute I open the app again, but against my expectations version 0.0.1 is still installed.

I have also tried to install and open version 0.0.1, then reboot the device, and then install version 0.0.2, but that has the same result.

**Windows 10 (regular):**

I also did the exact same thing as above on Windows 10 regular (my desktop), and there the update works fine.

**Device:**

- Model: Microsoft Lumia 650
- Software: Windows 10 Mobile
- RAM: 1 GB
- Version: 1607
- Systembuild: 10.0.14393.953
- Revisionnumber of firmware: 01078.00042.16352.50014
- Revisionnumber of hardware: 3.0.4.0

I hope someone has an idea of what I am doing wrong here :)

Any help is dearly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated the software to version 10.0.14393.1066. This resolved the issue.