# Unable to sideload UWP App to Windows phone 10

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-mobile

I just coded my first very simple UWP App for my Windows 10 phone (Blu Win HD LTE).

I created the package using VS 2017(by right clicking on my solution then store then create package). It gives me an appx file.

I then copy over the entire folder to my phone, install all dependencies, install the certificates but when I finally try to install the app, it asks me whether I want to install the app. I tap yes and the prompt disappears. That's it. Nothing happens, the app doesn't get installed.

I have tried appx, and appxbundle too. Can anyone rule out what mistake I am doing?

My Phone is running the Windows 10 update Version 1607 build 10.0.14393.693
Developer mode is enabled

Comment: So, WP8 or WP10? Tag one, not both. Judging by your question though, you should only have *tagged* as WP10.

Comment: Have you enabled developer mode in the settings on the phone ?wups, you have then ensure timing on the phone correct on earliere devices you needed sometimes to remove auto date and time. Have you tried deploying to the phone via vs?

Comment: @JTIM Tried removing auto date/time, didn't work.
No, I didn't find any option to deploy to phone using VS

Comment: That is standard, where you split to emulator you can change it to deploy to device

Comment: Your phone supports x64? I really doubt it does. And for phones the only available architecture is ARM AFAIK.

Comment: @JTIM it somehow worked

Comment: update to 10.0.14393.1066

Comment: have you installed the latest RS1 update for your phone? does it work now?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I got the latest update installed already... I tried deploying from VS and it solved the problem

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer and with a link to a similar issue where the build .1066 fixed an deploy issue

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 Mobile Version 1607 build 10.0.14393.693 is not the latest version. Connect to Wifi, charge your phone, [and search for new updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013235/windows-10-mobile-keep-device-up-to-date) under settings app->`Update & security` > `Phone update` > `Check for updates`

[image]

and install the Build 14393.1066. [This build seams to fix an app deployment issue, maybe also yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43394439/1466046).

Comment: there is no limitation on country base. Maybe your cell phone carrier delays it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the package for ARM only. The package created by  Visual studio by default is for x86,x64 and ARM all.

Uncheck the x86,x64 options.

On clicking the install button the popup will disappear and the phone will not show any progress on installing but the application will be shown automatically in the phone after some time.